# React Native Expo: Authentication with Identity Server 4

Tags: authentication, expo, react-native, identityserver4, bearer-token

I am trying to use the sample code from expo documentation "https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/" for IdentityServer4. I have created a React template from ASP.NET Core Web Application. When I run the react native app to redirect to the login page of the ASP application I can login but the problem is the window does not close to return the token. It logs in and then I go to the home page of the ASP application. I believe I am missing the redirect URL or the client is not setup the right way. Can someone help me how to set this up? Or what part am I missing?

Here is my client set up from the ASP application from the appsettings.json:

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "AAA": {
        "ClientId": "myclientid,
        "ClientName": "Native Client (Code with PKCE)",
        "RequireClientSecret": false,
        "RedirectUris": [ "io.expo.auth/@username/Auth" ],
        "AllowedGrantTypes": "GrantTypes.Code",
        "RequirePkce": "true",
        "AllowedScopes": ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
        "AllowOfflineAccess": "true",
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA",
        "ClientSecrets": [
          {
            "Value": "secretvalue"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

**Below is my React Native app:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as AuthSession from 'expo-auth-session';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const useProxy = true;

const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
  native: 'myApp://io.expo.auth/@username/Auth',
  useProxy,
});

export default function App() {
  const discovery = AuthSession.useAutoDiscovery('https://demo.identityserver.io');
  
  // Create and load an auth request
  const [request, result, promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId: 'myclientid',
      redirectUri,
      scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email', 'offline_access'],
    },
    discovery
  );

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Login!" disabled={!request} onPress={() => promptAsync({ useProxy })} />
      {result && <Text>{JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to fix on ur code:

1. On appsettings.json change `RedirectUris` to be a list, result would be like this:

```
"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "AAA": {
        "ClientId": "myclientid,
        "ClientName": "Native Client (Code with PKCE)",
        "RequireClientSecret": false,
        "RedirectUris": [ "io.expo.auth/@username/Auth" ],
        "AllowedGrantTypes": "GrantTypes.Code",
        "RequirePkce": "true",
        "AllowedScopes": [ "api" ],
        "AllowOfflineAccess": "true",
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA",
        "ClientSecrets": [
          {
            "Value": "secretvalue"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

Read more [here](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/topics/clients.html#defining-clients-in-appsettings-json)

2. Make sure URL listed on `RedirectUris` exist, and it match the value set for `redirectUri` on the native client. I'm no expo expert, you may use some sort of middleware but as far as I understand from your code above these URLs dont match.

Comment: To be honest I am not exactly sure what to put in as redirectUri  from the react native. That is why I didn't match the links and left them as they are.

Comment: @Jack redirect url should be ` https://auth.expo.io/@your-username/your-project-slug`, replace ur username & app name in the URL - I suggest you to read https://docs.expo.io/guides/authentication/ - Also avoid changing the question, if you need to just add changes on the bottom

Answer (score 0):

@nahidf: I have updated the url from the react native and the ASP app. The log in still is fine on the android app, but after I log in, the app stays open with the home page of that ASP app and not closing to return to react app and also return the token. Does the expo app have to be published because I am running it locally? Also, the ASP I have published it on a local server.

Comment: no need to publish, as long as the URL set in react app is a valid one it should be ok, what is the value of RedirectUris after u edited it?

Comment: On the RN i have this :


     const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({
       native: 'myApp://io.expo.auth/@Ajack/Auth',
       useProxy,
     });

where "myApp" is the slug in app.json and "Auth" is the scheme.

While in the identity server I have :

      "RedirectUris": [ "myApp://io.expo.auth/@Ajack/Auth" ],

Comment: do you use this URL on both client & also IdentityServer config? they should match as whole

Comment: Yes, they both match.

Comment: Anyone has any solution for this? Thanks